# Google ad activeview does not count correctly. Shows browser size is 0( bs: 0,0)

Tags: google-ads-api, activeview

I have google ad in web site.Ad is visible to client. But in google statistics viewability is 18-20%.
I inspected in browser.It shows browser size:0,0 px(bs:0,0).

sig: Cg0ArKJSzK9xkPVRs7FEEAE
id: lidar2
mcvt: 1003
p: 225,425,315,1153
mtos: 1003,1003,1003,1003,1003
tos: 1003,0,0,0,0
v: 20211202
bin: 7
avms: nio
**bs: 0,0**
mc: 1
if: 1
app: 0
itpl: 19
adk: 803334084
rs: 4
la: 0
cr: 0
vs: 4
r: v
rst: 1640861015262
rpt: 1292
isd: 0
lsd: 0
met: ce
wmsd: 0

Comment: Maybe try to explain the context. What you are trying to do and what the problem is in a little more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.